# Firefox - Load texture cross-domain (WebGL)

Tags: firefox, cross-domain, webgl, response-headers

I'm having a problem loading images cross-domain in Firefox for WebGL and it works fine in Chrome. 
I've implemented CORS on the server that has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in the response header.

The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" response made Chrome satisfied with cross-domain images but Firefox is not. Is Firefox still implementing CORS or am I just doing something wrong?

I'm using Firefox version 6.0.2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS for WebGL textures is not supported until [Firefox 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Cross-Domain_Textures).

Firefox 8 should be in the Beta channel very soon now, since Firefox 7 was released today.